# How can we check logs or debug Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

If edge happens to crash on some machines and we need to check the logs to see what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Edge is actually a Windows Process so you should be able to view the log in the event viewer. additionally you can use WinDGB or Visual Studio to further debug problems and crashes [image]

Comment: How can we debug edge if the issue is that it closes as soon as it opens? There are no logs in the event viewer for this issue.